# Calling a function set as a variable error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Tags: javascript

I'm following a leetcode solution and trying to understand it in my IDE, but when I try to call it I get the above error.

```
        var romanToInt = function(s) {
            const map = {
                I: 1,
                V: 5,
                X: 10,
                L: 50,
                C: 100,
                D: 500,
                M: 1000
            };
            let i = s.length;
            let result = 0;

            while (i--) {
                const curr = map[s.charAt(i)];
                const prev = map[s.charAt(i - 1)];

                result += curr; 

                if (prev < curr) {
                    result -= prev; 
                    i -= 1;
                }
            }

            return result;
        };
        romanToInt();
```

What should I do instead?

Comment: You call `romanToInt` without an argument, wheras the function definition clearly indicates a `s` parameter. You have to call the function with a string parameter (a roman number such as `"MCXI"`).

Comment: @Pierre when i add the ```s``` parameter I get ```Uncaught ReferenceError: s is not defined```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line causes the error:

```
let i = s.length;
```

When you call the function like this: `romanToInt();`
The argument `s` (`function(s) { ...`) is `undefined` as you pass nothing to the function in the parentheses.

`undefined` does not have the property `length`. This is what the error means. This property is available on strings, which means that you need to pass a string to the function like this:

```
romanToInt("MC");
```

The function will start to iterate over your string starting from the back going to the beginning.

See:

```js
var romanToInt = function(s) {
            const map = {
                I: 1,
                V: 5,
                X: 10,
                L: 50,
                C: 100,
                D: 500,
                M: 1000
            };
            let i = s.length;
            let result = 0;

            while (i--) {
                const curr = map[s.charAt(i)];
                const prev = map[s.charAt(i - 1)];

                result += curr; 

                if (prev < curr) {
                    result -= prev; 
                    i -= 1;
                }
            }

            return result;
        };
        var result = romanToInt("MC");
        alert(result); // show the result
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.
I had to call it like so:

```
romanToInt("V");
console.log("works", romanToInt("V"));
```